# Can I gather other iOS app's BLE connections in swift app?

Tags: swift, logging, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to gather GATT values for analysis my activities.

Specifically, I'm gathering fitbit app's livedata from PacketLogger.
By doing this I can get livedata every second.

However this configuration needs macbook, very difficult to carry.
So I want to make app can gather other app's BLE connection like PacketLogger.

If you have any knowledge, please help.

Comment: Use `centralManager(_:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:)`?

Comment: thank you EL Tomato ! :)
I think `centralManager(_:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:)` can get only Peripheral status.
so if I use this, I would be able to connect to tracker. but I cannot access other app's (Fitbit app) connection details.

Although, I have never tried this. I will challenge ! thk

Comment: I tried adbertisementData. but I didn't get fitbit app's ble connection datas are Notify, Write value. (Maybe, my usage is incorrect)

I would want to ask if it is technically possible...

Comment: You cannot intercept other app's Bluetooth traffic on iOS.  To get the live data you would need to write your own app to connect to the device and receive the data updates

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 !
It is not written on the apple developer. I understand fitbit's bluetooth authentication flow is private and I need to give up...

Comment: The internals of iOS doesn't allow to do such task (inspecting other apps Bluetooth communications). However, you could use apps like NRF Connect that save you the (minimal) cost of developing an app that scans the environment for BLE devices and lists services and characteristics. But you would still need to understand to what each service and characteristic corresponds.